# Html5 audio won't play in safari when the source is populated via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3.1, html5-audio

I am building a playlist in my Rails app and I am having some issues getting audio to play in Safari. If the html5 audio element's source is hard-coded, it plays just fine in safari but when it is populated via javascript, it does not play. this works just fine in Chrome and IE, but not in Safari.

Here is the Ruby for the playlist entry:

```
.playlist_column
  -@music_posts.each do |post|
    .entry{:id => post.id, :data => {:post_id => post.id, :source => post.mp3.url}}
```

and here is the audio element, preloaded with the first track's source:

```
.playlist_player
  %audio{:controls => "controls", :id => @music_posts.first.id}
    %source{:src => @music_posts.first.mp3.url, :type => "audio/mp3"}
```

Here is the JavaScript:

```
$(".entry").click(function(){
  var current_entry = $(this);
  var this_track = current_entry.data("source");
  var audio = $("audio").get(0);
  var audio_source = $("audio source");

  audio_source.attr("src", this_track);
  audio.load();
  audio.play();
```

});

When I inspect the audio element in safari, it looks exactly like it should, with the proper source:

```
<audio controls="controls" id="7">
  <source src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/blog/posts/5/song/07%20-%20Young%20Blood.mp3?1328052011" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
```

But it won't play and I am not seeing any errors, any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the HTML spec for the [src attribute on an existing source element](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-video-element.html#attr-source-src):

> Note: Dynamically modifying a source element and its attribute when the element is already inserted in a video or audio element will have no effect. To change what is playing, just use the src attribute on the media element directly, possibly making use of the canPlayType() method to pick from amongst available resources. Generally, manipulating source elements manually after the document has been parsed is an unnecessarily complicated approach.

Since you (theoretically) know that the audio file type is playable, you can just do

```
var audio = $("audio").get(0);
audio.src = this_track;
audio.load();
audio.play();
```

I just tested that in Safari and it appears to work correctly.

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. Since I am still growing my programming chops, I appreciate the help. Setting the source directly did the trick in Safari, even though Chrome and IE worked well the other way.

Answer (score 0):

```
type => "audio/mpeg"
```

That should fix it. A suggestion - please give id for audio elements and use it in jQuery instead of tag name.