# React doesn't play audio after setAttribute

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom

I have a React component that when I click play it iterates through an array of `id`s (from google drive file URL) stored in database and set `id` to `src=` for the `<source>` tag and plays the sound from that URL. But it doesn't work as expected. But when I hard code the whole URL into the `src`, it works.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Axios from 'axios';

export default function Sound() {
  const [songs, setSongs] = useState([]);
  const [playing, setPlaying] = useState(false);
  const [volume, setVolume] = useState(0);

  const thisAudio = document.getElementById('audio');
  const link = 'http://docs.google.com/uc?export=open&id=';

  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get('/sound')
    .then(res => {
      const resData = res.data;
      setSongs(resData.songs); // [0B4gNjF-sbbvHTTV1QUg0NERXTzQ,...]
      setPlaying(resData.playing); // True
      setVolume(resData.volume); // 0.5
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }, []);

  const playSound = async () => {
    await document.getElementById('src').setAttribute('src', link + songs[0]);
    await document.getElementById('src').setAttribute('type', 'audio/mp3');
    console.log(thisAudio);
    /* Log result:
    <audio id="audio">
        <source id="src" src="http://docs.google.com/uc?export=open&id=0B4gNjF-sbbvHTTV1QUg0NERXTzQ" type="audio/mp3"></source>
    </audio>
    Exactly what I want to see here.
    */
    thisAudio.play();
    thisAudio.volume = volume;
  }

  const changeVolume = () => {
    console.log(document.getElementById('audio'));
    /*
    After click playSound, I click this and the result is the same as the above, nothing wrong (I guess)
    */
    thisAudio.volume = 0.3;
  }

  return (
    <div className='sound'>
      <audio id='audio'>
        <source id='src' >
        </source>

        {/* This one works
        <source id='src' src={link + '0B4gNjF-sbbvHTTV1QUg0NERXTzQ'} type='audio/mp3' >
        </source>
        */}

      </audio>
      <button onClick={playSound}>Play Sound</button>
      <button onClick={changeVolume}>Change Volume</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I use async to make sure the elements to are loaded then `play()` can execute.
I don't know why this approach doesn't work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [HTML spec says when the element exists already, don't modify a `source` element, just set the `src` on the `audio` element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#attr-source-src):

> Dynamically modifying a source element and its attribute when the
>   element is already inserted in a video or audio element will have no
>   effect. To change what is playing, just use the src attribute on the
>   media element directly, possibly making use of the canPlayType()
>   method to pick from amongst available resources. Generally,
>   manipulating source elements manually after the document has been
>   parsed is an unnecessarily complicated approach.

I found this via [Html5 audio won't play in safari when the source is populated via JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271006/html5-audio-wont-play-in-safari-when-the-source-is-populated-via-javascript).

Comment: Weird, I tried document.getElementById('src').src = '...' like the answer but it doesn't work.

Comment: That's the wrong element to target, that's still a `source` element. You want to use the id "`audio`."

Comment: Thanks, 
`document.getElementById('audio').src = '...'` fixed it.